# Place Autocomplete Address Form

Tags: forms

I created a registration form for a website and I included the Place Autocomplete Address Form provided by Google to fill the Country, Province and City fields.

It works perfectly.  However, I use Google Analytics and I have seen that a certain number of users leave the process before completing the registration, as if something went wrong and couldn’t complete it.

The form itself is quite simple, so I checked it with some possible errors.
It has several requested fields, so the form reloads partially to display a popup asking you to add the information or data in each case. The fields filled out correctly keep de information. All but the ones filled out by the Google API, which simply disappear. And I am not talking about the information added to them, the fields themselves are missing, removed from the code.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, this question is likely to get closed because It's pretty hard to understand your question. You need to be specific. Explain what you have already tried - you haven't even specified what language you are using! This helps as it immediately pushes the question towards people who know about it. When you google 'Place Autocomplete Address Form' it actually links to SO and tells you what tag to use. Rephrase your question so it is more specific and targeted, add the right tags, and explain what you have tried already and you should get more positive responses.

Comment: Please provide a detailed description of your problem along with the code which you have tried as per SO guideline. Also tag your question properly

Answer (score 0):

1. I created a registration form.
2. Some fields (Country, Province and City) are filled by this API:

[Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=es-419)

The code I used is on that page.

3. If you fill out the form and make any mistake or fail to fill any requested field, for instance, adding different passwords in the Password and Re-write Password fields, the form realoads partially displaying a message requesting you to fill them properly.

By them, the fields to be filled by the Google API are gone, removed from the code.

The problem is that when the user filled the, in the example, password and re-write password fields properly, another message popups requesting to fill the country, province and city fields.

Is it clear enough now?